# defunct zombie process of my file server program

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets, fork

I've a file server program based on sockets which uses `fork` to serve multiple clients at a time. After running this server program when I do `ps -ef` I am getting a lot of `<defunct>` child processes of my server. How can I resolve this problem? Below is my server code.
Thanks in advance.

```
/* This is the server for a very simple file transfer
   service.  This is a "concurrent server" that can
   handle requests from multiple simultaneous clients.
   For each client:
    - get file name and check if it exists
    - send size of file to client
    - send file to client, a block at a time
    - close connection with client
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MY_PORT_ID 60841 
#define MAXLINE 256
#define MAXSIZE 262144 

#define ACK                   2
#define NACK                  3
#define REQUESTFILE           100
#define COMMANDNOTSUPPORTED   150
#define COMMANDSUPPORTED      160
#define BADFILENAME           200
#define FILENAMEOK            400

int writen(int sd,char *ptr,int size);
int readn(int sd,char *ptr,int size);

main()  {

   int sockid, newsd, pid, clilen;
   struct sockaddr_in my_addr, client_addr;   
    long int milsecS, milsecE;

   //printf("server: creating socket\n");
   if ((sockid = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0)) < 0)
     {printf("server: socket error : %d\n", errno); exit(0); }

   //printf("server: binding my local socket\n");
   bzero((char *) &my_addr,sizeof(my_addr));
   my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   my_addr.sin_port = htons(MY_PORT_ID);
   my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htons(INADDR_ANY);
   if (bind(sockid ,(struct sockaddr *) &my_addr,sizeof(my_addr)) < 0)
     {printf("server: bind  error :%d\n", errno); exit(0); }
   //printf("server: starting listen \n");
   if (listen(sockid,5) < 0)
     { printf("server: listen error :%d\n",errno);exit(0);}                                        

   while(1==1) { 
     /* ACCEPT A CONNECTION AND THEN CREATE A CHILD TO DO THE WORK */
     /* LOOP BACK AND WAIT FOR ANOTHER CONNECTION                  */
     //printf("server: starting accept\n");
     clilen=sizeof((struct sockaddr *) &client_addr);
     if ((newsd = accept(sockid ,(struct sockaddr *) &client_addr,
                                      &clilen)) < 0)
        {printf("server: accept  error :%d\n", errno); exit(0); }

    /* START TIME */
    struct timeval tvBegin, tvEnd;
    struct timeval *tvB, *tvE;

    gettimeofday(&tvBegin, NULL);
    tvB=&tvBegin;
    milsecS=(tvB->tv_sec)*1000000L-tvB->tv_usec;
    //printf("Start in milliseconds: %ld\n", milsecS);   

        //printf("server: return from accept, socket for this ftp: %d\n",
                                       //newsd);
     if ( (pid=fork()) == 0) {
         /* CHILD PROC STARTS HERE. IT WILL DO ACTUAL FILE TRANSFER */
         close(sockid);   /* child shouldn't do an accept */
         doftp(newsd, milsecS);
         close (newsd);
         exit(0);         /* child all done with work */
         }
      /* PARENT CONTINUES BELOW HERE */
     close(newsd);        /* parent all done with client, only child */
     }              /* will communicate with that client from now on */
}   


/* CHILD PROCEDURE, WHICH ACTUALLY DOES THE FILE TRANSFER */
doftp(int newsd, long int milsecS)
  {       
    int i,fsize,fd,msg_ok,fail,fail1,req,c,ack;
    int no_read ,num_blks , num_blks1,num_last_blk,num_last_blk1,tmp;
    char fname[MAXLINE];
    char out_buf[MAXSIZE];
    FILE *fp;
    long int sMilsec, milsecE;
    sMilsec=milsecS;
    float schDelay; //To calculate schedule delay
    char schDelayS[30]; 
    struct timeval tvEnd;
    struct timeval *tvE;

     no_read = 0;
     num_blks = 0;
     num_last_blk = 0; 


     /* START SERVICING THE CLIENT */ 

     /* get command code from client.*/
     /* only one supported command: 100 -  get a file */
     req = 0;
     if((readn(newsd,(char *)&req,sizeof(req))) < 0)
     {printf("server: read error %d\n",errno);exit(0);}
     req = ntohs(req);
     //printf("Req is: %d\n", req);
     //printf("server: client request code is: %d\n",req);
     if (req!=REQUESTFILE) {
     printf("server: unsupported operation. goodbye\n");
         /* reply to client: command not OK  (code: 150) */
         msg_ok = COMMANDNOTSUPPORTED; 
         msg_ok = htons(msg_ok);
         if((writen(newsd,(char *)&msg_ok,sizeof(msg_ok))) < 0)
            {printf("server: write error :%d\n",errno);exit(0);}
         exit(0);
         }

     /* reply to client: command OK  (code: 160) */
     msg_ok = COMMANDSUPPORTED; 
     msg_ok = htons(msg_ok);
     if((writen(newsd,(char *)&msg_ok,sizeof(msg_ok))) < 0)
             {printf("server: write error :%d\n",errno);exit(0);}

    fail = FILENAMEOK;
    if((read(newsd,fname,MAXLINE)) < 0) {
        printf("server: filename read error :%d\n",errno);
        fail = BADFILENAME ;
        }

     /* IF SERVER CANT OPEN FILE THEN INFORM CLIENT OF THIS AND TERMINATE */
   //printf("File name is: %s\n", fname);
     if((fp = fopen(fname,"r")) == NULL) /*cant open file*/
        fail = BADFILENAME;

     tmp = htons(fail);
     if((writen(newsd,(char *)&tmp,sizeof(tmp))) < 0)
        {printf("server: write error :%d\n",errno);exit(0);   }
     if(fail == BADFILENAME) {printf("server cant open file\n");
                            close(newsd);exit(0);}
     //printf("server: filename is %s\n",fname);

    req = 0;
    if ((readn(newsd,(char *)&req,sizeof(req))) < 0)
                  {printf("server: read error :%d\n",errno);exit(0);}
    //printf("server: start transfer command, %d, received\n", ntohs(req));


   /*SERVER GETS FILESIZE AND CALCULATES THE NUMBER OF BLOCKS OF 
     SIZE = MAXSIZE IT WILL TAKE TO TRANSFER THE FILE. ALSO CALCULATE
     NUMBER OF BYTES IN THE LAST PARTIALLY FILLED BLOCK IF ANY. 
     SEND THIS INFO TO CLIENT, RECEIVING ACKS */
    //printf("server: starting transfer\n");
    fsize = 0;ack = 0;   
    while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) {fsize++;}
    num_blks = fsize / MAXSIZE; 
    num_blks1 = htons(num_blks);
    num_last_blk = fsize % MAXSIZE; 
    num_last_blk1 = htons(num_last_blk);
    if((writen(newsd,(char *)&num_blks1,sizeof(num_blks1))) < 0)
             {printf("server: write error :%d\n",errno);exit(0);}
    //printf("server: told client there are %d blocks\n", num_blks);  
    if((readn(newsd,(char *)&ack,sizeof(ack))) < 0)
        {printf("server: ack read error :%d\n",errno);exit(0); }          
    if (ntohs(ack) != ACK) {
      printf("client: ACK not received on file size\n");
      exit(0);
      }
    if((writen(newsd,(char *)&num_last_blk1,sizeof(num_last_blk1))) < 0)
       {printf("server: write error :%d\n",errno);exit(0);}
    //printf("server: told client %d bytes in last block\n", num_last_blk);  
    if((readn(newsd,(char *)&ack,sizeof(ack))) < 0)
        {printf("server: ack read error :%d\n",errno);exit(0); }
    if (ntohs(ack) != ACK) {
      printf("server: ACK not received on file size\n");
      exit(0);
      }
    rewind(fp);    


    /* ACTUAL FILE TRANSFER STARTS  BLOCK BY BLOCK*/       

    gettimeofday(&tvEnd, NULL);
    tvE=&tvEnd;
    milsecE=(tvE->tv_sec)*1000000L-tvE->tv_usec;
    //printf("End time in milliseconds: %ld\n", milsecE);
    schDelay=fabs((milsecE-sMilsec)/1000);
    htonl(schDelay); 
    //printf("Delay is: %f\n", schDelay);

  for(i= 0; i < num_blks; i ++) { 
      no_read = fread(out_buf,sizeof(char),MAXSIZE,fp);
      if (no_read == 0) {printf("server: file read error\n");exit(0);}
      if (no_read != MAXSIZE)
              {printf("server: file read error : no_read is less\n");exit(0);}
      if((writen(newsd,out_buf,MAXSIZE)) < 0)
                 {printf("server: error sending block:%d\n",errno);exit(0);}
      if((readn(newsd,(char *)&ack,sizeof(ack))) < 0)
                 {printf("server: ack read  error :%d\n",errno);exit(0);}
      if (ntohs(ack) != ACK) {
          printf("server: ACK not received for block %d\n",i);
          exit(0);
          }
     // printf(" %d...",i);
      }

   if (num_last_blk > 0) { 
      //printf("%d\n",num_blks);
      no_read = fread(out_buf,sizeof(char),num_last_blk,fp); 
      if (no_read == 0) {printf("server: file read error\n");exit(0);}
      if (no_read != num_last_blk) 
            {printf("server: file read error : no_read is less 2\n");exit(0);}
      if((writen(newsd,out_buf,num_last_blk)) < 0)
                 {printf("server: file transfer error %d\n",errno);exit(0);}
      if((readn(newsd,(char *)&ack,sizeof(ack))) < 0)
             {printf("server: ack read  error %d\n",errno);exit(0);}
      if (ntohs(ack) != ACK) {
          printf("server: ACK not received last block\n");
          exit(0);
          }
      }
   // else printf("\n");

   /* FILE TRANSFER ENDS */
   //printf("server: FILE TRANSFER COMPLETE on socket %d\n",newsd);
   fclose(fp);
   close(newsd);
  }


/*
  TO TAKE CARE OF THE POSSIBILITY OF BUFFER LIMMITS IN THE KERNEL FOR THE
 SOCKET BEING REACHED (WHICH MAY CAUSE READ OR WRITE TO RETURN FEWER CHARACTERS
  THAN REQUESTED), WE USE THE FOLLOWING TWO FUNCTIONS */  

int readn(int sd,char *ptr,int size)
{         int no_left,no_read;
          no_left = size;
          while (no_left > 0) 
                     { no_read = read(sd,ptr,no_left);
                       if(no_read <0)  return(no_read);
                       if (no_read == 0) break;
                       no_left -= no_read;
                       ptr += no_read;
                     }
          return(size - no_left);
}

int writen(int sd,char *ptr,int size)
{         int no_left,no_written;
          no_left = size;
          while (no_left > 0) 
                     { no_written = write(sd,ptr,no_left);
                       if(no_written <=0)  return(no_written);
                       no_left -= no_written;
                       ptr += no_written;
                     }
          return(size - no_left);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Become zombie process:

When a child process finish its job, and terminate, the parent process exist & didn't call wait() for it, then it become zombie.

### How to remove zombie:

- Let parent process call `wait()` on child process, then kernel will clear terminated process properly instead let it become zombie.
- or, terminate the parent process, then `init` process will become its parent, and would terminate & clear the child process properly when it terminate.

---

### In your case:

So, probably u created child process with `fork()` without making the parent process `wait()` for it, and the parent process didn't terminate.
Thus, then the child process finish its job, it become zombie.

You can try to use `wait()` on the child process.

---

### To your question in comment

**Where to add `wait()`:**

- First u need to decide which wait to use according to your logic, there are `wait()` / `waitpid()` / `waitid()`, where `wait()` is most simple one with least control. If it's ok to block the parent process while wait, then `wait()` is fine, otherwise need `waitpid()` or `waitid()`. Refer to `man` page for details of each function.
- After decide which wait to use, then usually add the wait function after `fork()`, before end of `main()`, probably with a loop to handle multiple child process, and check return value of wait to decide the next step.

**Books:** `man` page are quite good, but linux programming book(e.g `TLPI`) might give great help.

---

### Code example

Here is a simple test program I wrote when learning linux programming, which create multiple child process & wait on them.

**wait_test.c**

```
// wait() test
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int wait_test() {
    pid_t cpid;
    int i, max_child = 5;

    // create child process,
    for(i=1; i<=max_child; i++) {
        switch(cpid=fork()) {
            case -1: // failed
                printf("error while fork()\n");
                exit(errno);
            case 0: // success, child process goes here
                sleep(i);
                printf("child [%d], going to exit\n",(int)getpid());
                _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
                break;
            default: // success, parent process goes here
                printf("parent [%d], child created [%d]\n", (int)getpid(), (int)cpid);
                break;
        }
    }

    // wait child to terminate
    int status;
    while(1) {
        if((cpid = wait(&status)) == -1) {
            if(errno == ECHILD) {
                printf("no more child\n");
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            } else {
                printf("error while wait()\n");
                exit(-1);
            }
        }
        printf("parent [%d], child [%d] exit with [%d]\n", (int)getpid(), (int)cpid, status);
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    wait_test();
    return 0;
}
```

**compile on linux:** `gcc -Wall wait_test.c`

**execute:** `./a.out`

It gives a basic view of how child process & wait might work.

---

### @Update: SIGCHLD signal

As `@alk` commented, use `SIGCHLD` signal handler is another way to call wait, it could be simpler, but seems there are trick in it, and easy to get bug.

Following is some description base on my **limited** knowledge of using `SIGCHLD` signal, just take it as a tip, not the exact sample.

**How to use `SIGCHID signal`:**

By default, `SIGCHID` signal is ignored by process, but could register a handler on it.

Due to standard signal is temporarily blocked & not queued, means multiple signal could be sent & the process may only see it happen once,
thus whenever receive this signal, should use a loop of `waitpid()` with `WNOHANG` option, to handle all terminated child process.

The handler function might looks like this:

```
void sigchld_handler() {
    int local_errno = errno; // backup errno,

    while (waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0)
        continue;

    errno = local_errno; // restore errno,
}
```

And register the handler on parent process, before call folk(), by:

```
if(signal(SIGCHLD, sigchld_handler) == SIG_ERR) {
    printf("error signal()");
    return errno;
}
```

Then, when a child process terminate, the parent process will receive a `SIGCHLD` signal, and call the handler function, which wait child process, thus help to clear child process instead of let it becoming a zombie.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. Where should I add this `wait()` method exactly?
`if ( (pid=fork()) == 0) {
         /* CHILD PROC STARTS HERE. IT WILL DO ACTUAL FILE TRANSFER */
         close(sockid);   /* child shouldn't do an accept */
         doftp(newsd, milsecS);
         close (newsd);
         exit(0);         /* child all done with work */
         }
      /* PARENT CONTINUES BELOW HERE */
     close(newsd);        /* parent all done with client, only child */
     } `

Comment: Regarding "Where to call `wait()`" one might also consider to have the parent install a signal handler for `SIGCHLD`, which calls `wait*()`.

Comment: @alk Yeah, that could be a simpler solution, and answer updated.

Comment: Thank you very much Eric n alk. Adding `waitpid` after `fork` resolved my issue :)